# Paths not resolving correctly using host name on local network - Mac

Tags: networking, mac, apache-http-server

I'm using a Mac as a server and have local names resolving using Apache's http-vhosts.conf file.  I'm using this server as a development platform that I want to essentially mirror my Ubuntu web server.  The issue I'm having is although the name myserver.local resolves to the right place, any paths in the .htaccess file are not honored.

For example:
RewriteRule /search /cgi-bin/search.pl

I get a File Not Found error even though the file is in the right place.  The server isn't treating the backslash like it would on a domain.  Even though myserver.local is setup in the hosts file and the http-vhosts.conf file, it doesn't see my files because it can't follow the path.  Make sense?  Any idea why?

UPDATE:  This maybe an issue with the cgi-bin directory not being mapped properly.  My error logs say Apache is looking in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. How do I map the cgi-bin on a per domain/hostname basis?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found it.  It was an entry I had to replace in the http.conf file.

ScriptAliasMatch "^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/cgi-bin/(.+)"   "/Users/username/Sites/$1/cgi-bin/$2"